# nvidia control panel reporting 60hz on 144hz monitor. how to make ubuntu output 144hz?

Tags: gnome, nvidia, xorg, framerate

OK, I'm using Ubuntu Gnome 15.04 wit gnome shell 3.16.1 and nvidia control panel 349.16 (think that's the newest one, correct me if i'm wrong)

I have no idea why it says 60hz under the name of my monitor when it should say 144hz.

Also in windows 8.1 when I move my cursor in circles it looks like there's more frames per second. That might be placebo tough.

So if anyone were as kind to answer/propose a solution about this, it would be very kind.

Comment: So nvidia control panel reports 60 MHz, but does say your screen with its OSD ?

Comment: I don't know, because i found an answer by googling the same thing just with 30hz to 60hz. read my answer bellow.

Comment: also Hz not MHz. M = Mega = 1.000.000 (million)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found an easy fix

```
xrandr --output DVI-D-0 --mode 1920x1080 --rate 144
```

Comment: Why don't you just switch frequency in Nvidia control panel?

Comment: I remember that the setting didn't go over 60Hz before i did this.